# Java Performance Analysis for business methods

Tags: java, performance

I've a business method implemented in two different ways.  I want to analyze the performance of the implementations. How should I do this?

Comment: You can make your own input date for those methods. Then detect time before method start and after method finish work and ready :)
(use System.getCurrentTimeMIllis())

Comment: what's a 'business' method?

Answer (score 1):

Read about micro benchmarks [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java) then use [Caliper](https://code.google.com/p/caliper/)

Answer (score 0):

Write a timing aspect and use something like JMeter to create a high volume test.  Keep statistics on performance: min, mean, max, standard deviation, quartiles.  Do Student-T test on both to see if the difference in means is significantly different.

If it's a business method, you'll need to generate sufficient scrubbed data to drive the application.  It's easy if a single request is sufficient, but you'll have to write a randomized message generator if not.

That should tell you what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

Write a small app that uses that class and then you could use [VisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/) to profile your class.